# What is "mapped stream" mentioned in the docs for flatMap?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

This question is not about flatMap() in general. I want to understand the documentation of flatMap.

Documentation says:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element
> of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by
> applying the provided mapping function to each element.

Assume we have the below code:

```html
List<List<Integer>> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3), Arrays.asList(4,5,6));
list.stream()
    .flatMap(lst -> lst.stream())
    .forEach(val -> System.out.println(val));
```

As per the docs, "each element of this stream" would mean the lists `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]`. Mapping function is `List::stream` and applying this function on the two lists would give us two stream objects of type - `Stream<String>`. Now I am not able to understand how we get the final output as `Stream<String>` and not `Stream<Stream<String>>`. (I know we would get the latter if we use `stream.map()` instead of `stream.flatMap()`)

However, if we follow the docs shouldn't we get `Stream<Stream<String>>`?

And can someone please explain the meaning of the term **mapped stream** in the context of this example? What will be the type/value of the **mapped stream**? What are the "contents of this mapped stream"?

Please help me understand this doc.

Comment: Honestly: what does it matter what the words *specifically* refer to? It is clear what the result actually is: apply the mapping function to the elements and then concat all the resulting sub streams into one big stream.

Comment: @luk2302 I read some tutorials and blogs and understood how flatMap works. However, I wanted to verify what I understood from those tutorials. For the few examples I could think of, it worked correctly. Also, I wanted to know the gaps in my understanding of the docs because I want to be able to understand these operations from the docs. I don't know any significant advantages of doing that, but it would help to consult docs for trivial things rather than going through tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of the mapped stream are the *elements* in the stream returned by `mapper`. A regular `map(List::stream)` would return a stream of streams, as you suggested. The point of `flatMap` (as indicated in the name) is to "flatten" the result by discarding the inner stream wrappers and combining all the contained elements into one stream.